# Push notification to iOS devices fails when invalid token

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

When sending a push notification it works correctly until it hits a invalid device id (token) and the push notifications stop sending.

E.g. So if the invalid token was at the start of the array the rest of the devices wouldn't get a notification.

Does anyone have any idea how to stop this or how I should handle the invalid tokens?

invalid token:

`4016d0fb5207c3f7652c499f970a5f0c888f2a733bdaf4965f4de0aa7d4e1d03`

valid tokens:

`7938f3efb9064a830afce762d843eb5fa67131237ef9a8808b3e2d3c205f530b` `e9335ed68a4f02c4284ae4b8edfda09fedaff4426c8c017d254c3d52c64ba716` `8d3d704618580a065ae4055561b11c662a667113aecd296ed07fe55d0650b596`

```
$tokens = array("4016d0fb5207c3f7652c499f970a5f0c888f2a733bdaf4965f4de0aa7d4e1d03", "7938f3efb9064a830afce762d843eb5fa67131237ef9a8808b3e2d3c205f530b", "e9335ed68a4f02c4284ae4b8edfda09fedaff4426c8c017d254c3d52c64ba716", "8d3d704618580a065ae4055561b11c662a667113aecd296ed07fe55d0650b596");

push_notification($tokens, 0);

function push_notification($tokens, $invalidTokenKey){
    //Setup notification message
    $body = array();
    $body['aps'] = array('alert' => 'My push notification message!');
    $body['aps']['badge'] = 1;

    //Setup stream (connect to Apple Push Server)
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', CERTIFICATES_APNS_PASSPHRASE);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', CERTIFICATES_APNS);
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    stream_set_blocking ($fp, 0); //This allows fread() to return right away when there are no errors. But it can also miss errors during last seconds of sending, as there is a delay before error is  returned. Workaround is to pause briefly AFTER sending last notification, and then do one more fread() to see if anything else is there.

    if (!$fp) {
        echo "Failed to connect (stream_socket_client): $err $errstrn";
    } else {
        $apple_expiry = time() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60); //Keep push alive (waiting for delivery) for 90 days
        for ($i = $invalidTokenKey; $i < count($tokens); $i++) { 
            $apple_identifier = $i;
            $deviceToken = $tokens[$i];
            $payload = json_encode($body);
            //Enhanced Notification
            $msg = pack("C", 1) . pack("N", $apple_identifier) . pack("N", $apple_expiry) . pack("n", 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack("n", strlen($payload)) . $payload;
            //SEND PUSH
            fwrite($fp, $msg); 
            //We can check if an error has been returned while we are sending, but we also need to check once more after we are done sending in case there was a delay with error response.
            checkAppleErrorResponse($fp);
        }

        //Workaround to check if there were any errors during the last seconds of sending.
        usleep(500000); //Pause for half a second. Note I tested this with up to a 5 minute pause, and the error message was still available to be retrieved

        checkAppleErrorResponse($fp);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}








//FUNCTION to check if there is an error response from Apple
//         Returns TRUE if there was and FALSE if there was not
function checkAppleErrorResponse($fp) {
   //byte1=always 8, byte2=StatusCode, bytes3,4,5,6=identifier(rowID). Should return nothing if OK.
   $apple_error_response = fread($fp, 6);
   //NOTE: Make sure you set stream_set_blocking($fp, 0) or else fread will pause your script and wait forever when there is no response to be sent.

   if ($apple_error_response) {
        //unpack the error response (first byte 'command" should always be 8)
        $error_response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $apple_error_response);

        if ($error_response['status_code'] == '0') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '0-No errors encountered';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '1') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '1-Processing error';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '2') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '2-Missing device token';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '3') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '3-Missing topic';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '4') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '4-Missing payload';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '5') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '5-Invalid token size';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '6') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '6-Invalid topic size';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '7') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '7-Invalid payload size';
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '8') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '8-Invalid token';
            $invalidTokenKey =  $error_response['identifier'] + 1;
            push_notification($tokens, $invalidTokenKey);
        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '255') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '255-None (unknown)';
        } else {
            $error_response['status_code'] = $error_response['status_code'] . '-Not listed';
        }
        return true;
   } 
   return false;
}
```

Comment: After invalid token when you using correct token....still notification not working...?

Comment: @GouravJoshi - Correct - So if the invalid token was at the start of the array of tokens then the rest of the devices wouldn't get a notification.

Comment: Currently are you testing these?. If yes then plz ensure from iOS end that they should not pass any placeholder value. Because sometimes we need to test from simulator or virtual Device. So a invalid token may arised.

Comment: @GouravJoshi - These are from iOS devices, none of them are from simulator or virtual devices.

Comment: Are these tokens updating frequently...?

Comment: @GouravJoshi - You only get a new device token when the application installed or removed then reinstalled.

Comment: yes correct.....Please ensure from ios end...

Comment: @GouravJoshi - That's how it's working at the moment, but i'm still getting some invalid tokens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129886/discussion-between-gourav-joshi-and-chris-beckett).

Comment: @ChrisBeckett I am facing the same issue, Did we get any solution for this ?

Comment: @Rayiez - Nope i never got to the bottom of this, when you use the feedback from apple server it makes the push notifications bit slower because you're having to run multiple checks before sending the notification. 

I just feel apples push notifications aren't as good as the android notifications yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should handle errors raised when you sent an invalid token and continue to send next token
2. you should handle invalid tokens from feedback service (feedback.push.apple.com) and remove that tokens from the list of your tokens

Your example code doesn't care about these things and that is why it stops working.

Comment: Have you got any examples of the feedback.push.apple?